# Sampling of a Gaussian posterior

Tags: bayesian, sampling

Sorry for my simple doubt, but I'm quite newbie and don't clearly get how to sample the posterior Bayesian distribution. My likelihood and prior are normal and I know how to calculate the posterior. How do I sample now? Can someone explain it in the simplest way?

---

EDIT:

Bayes theorem states: 
$$
p(θ|y)=\frac{p(y|θ)p(θ)}{p(y)}
$$

1. When I am sampling, what example do I sample for the posterior?
2. I read that the `rnorm` command (in R) can easily sample; I gather the syntax would be: `rnorm(n samples, mean, std)`. Is this kind of sampling as valid as MCMC? What is it executing there exactly?
3. Is sampling from a normal posterior equal to sampling from an isolated normal distribution?

Comment: Welcome to our site! It isn't really clear what you're asking here at the moment, I think you are going to have to be rather more specific. If you are just looking for R code, note that questions asking how something is done in a particular language or software package are off-topic here - have a look at our [help/on-topic].

Comment: I agree with @Silverfish. This question looks about R code which is more suitable for Stack Overflow. The posterior that you have obtained should also be a Normal distribution, so you can use `rnorm` in R.

Comment: @Greenparker Without a reproducible example, I don't think the question in its current state is well-suited for SO either.

Comment: I can imagine this having enough statistical content to be on topic here. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your model? At present, I'm not sure if there's much here that can be answered.

Comment: I think this has enough statistical content to be reopened now.

Comment: If you know the distribution of your posterior and you have a function to sample from such a distribution (such as rnorm) then yes you can simply use that function to obtain samples from your posterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that the `rnorm` command (in R) can easily sample; I gather the
>   syntax would be: `rnorm(n samples, mean, std)`. Is this kind of sampling
>   as valid as MCMC? What is it executing there exactly?

In principle, sampling form a posterior distribution is the same as sampling from any other distribution. If the distribution is of a known form (like a Gaussian, Gamma, Inverse Gamma, Beta etc), then you can use inbuilt functions in `R` to sample from these.

These functions like `rnorm` use iid sampling techniques, and **not** MCMC. This is a good thing. MCMC produces correlated samples that are *not* identically distributed. MCMC is used when iid sampling techniques fail. Unfortunately, in many Bayesian settings, the posterior distribution is not a known distribution, and of a complicated form. Sampling from such a distribution often requires MCMC.

However, known posterior distributions are sampled from using inverse CDF, variable transformation or Rejection sampling techniques which provide iid samples. I am not sure what `rnorm` uses, but one of the most common ways of sampling from a Normal distribution is the [Box-Mueller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) transformation.

So in short, if your posterior distribution is of a known form, and there exists a function to sample from it, go ahead and use that function.